# Expose saved/static target variable to scope outside

Tags: fortran, language-lawyer

Is the following code where a local, `save`d variable is exposed to an outside scope valid Fortran(>=2003) code?

I intentionally did not specify a year for the standard. If the answers differ for different standards, assuming that pointers are supported, I would be also happy to hear the answer.

```
program test_save
    implicit none

    integer, pointer :: ptr

    ptr => get_number(5)

    write(*, *) ptr

contains

    function get_number(n) result(res)
        integer, intent(in) :: n
        integer, pointer :: res
        integer, target, save :: internal_n
        internal_n = n
        res => internal_n
    end function
end program
```

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with this in Fortran90 and onwards, but I'm not the person to quote chapter and verse of the standard at you.

Comment: This can be quite hard to answer in the positive (so much of the Fortran standard is about _restrictions_ and you won't find many parts which says "a Fortran program is allowed to ..."). What standard of proof are you hoping to find?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point to consider is whether the target of `res` remains defined when the function exits (F2018 19.6.6p1(16)). Because the target has the `SAVE` attribute, it does remain defined (F2018 19.6.6p1(3)), and therefore the pointer remains defined.